# Initialized int being casted to list by python despite explicitly casting int

Tags: python, python-3.x

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVtoV.png)

why is the explicitly converted int being identified as a list. Problem also exist without the explicit casting. I am not sure what the issue is.

```
def longestSubstringWithK(full_string, k):
    window = {}

    longest_substring = 0


    smallest= int(0)
    for index, letter in enumerate(full_string):
        window[letter] = index

        if len(window) > k:
            smallest = min(window.values())

            del(window[full_string[smallest]])
            smallest = smallest + 1
            longest_substring = max(longest_substring, index - smallest+1)
    return longest_substring

word = "eceba"
print(longestSubstringWithK(word,2))
```

Comment: Could you post your code rather than an image of it? See also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I will check it out and I have posted the code

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest that `smallest` would be anything other than an `int`. Unless you have redefined `int` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: to be sure you can use: `print(type(smallest))` and see what the output is. For me it's `<class 'int'>`

Comment: It looks to me to just be an error in the type inference system of IDE you're using.

Comment: btw. There is no ‘casting’ in python. You meant to write ‘smallest = 0’.

Comment: I'm able to run your code (getting a result of 2).  I think it should be 3 (i.e. 'ece).  I don't think this is a translation of the algorithm.  I'll post my translation.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I think, since what you showed on the image, that is a problem with your IDE. Make sure that you are doing the cast correctly by debugging or print(type(YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME)).

Probably is not recognizing as a cast and only as list since the init is similar.

Depending in your IDE you can go open an issue so they can upgrade their IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**Incorrect indentation causes the wrong answer in your code.**

```
if len(window) > k:
    smallest = min(window.values())

    del(window[full_string[smallest]])
    smallest = smallest + 1
    longest_substring = max(longest_substring, index - smallest+1)
```

**Should instead be**

```
 if len(window) > k:
     smallest = min(window.values())

     del(window[full_string[smallest]])
     smallest = smallest + 1

 longest_substring = max(longest_substring, index - smallest+1)
```

With this change, your code correctly returns 3 for

```
print(longestSubstringWithK(word,2))
```